# Rename directories based on number of files within in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, rename

I have the following layout:

- d1

  - f1
  - f2
  - f3
- d2

  - f4
  - f5
- d3

  - f6
  - f7
  - f8
  - d4

    - f9

What I want to do is rename the root directories to contain the number of (recursive) files contained within.
The format isn't super important as long as it's not too long. I want to be able to run this script as a cron every hour or so to update the directory names, so after the first run it will look like this:

- 3-d1

  - f1
  - f2
  - f3
- 2-d2

  - f4
  - f5
- 4-d3

  - f6
  - f7
  - f8
  - d4

    - f9

Then after the second run, maybe a few more files will have been added and removed, and now it looks like this:

- 1-d1

  - f1
- 4-d2

  - f2
  - f3
  - f4
  - f5
- 10-d3

  - f6
  - f7
  - f8
  - d4

    - f9
    - f10
    - f11
    - f12
    - f13
    - f14
    - f15

I have the following bash script so far, but I can't figure out how to do the regex replacement on the filename

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGETPATH=/home/pritchea/test
for CURDIR in `ls -l $TARGETPATH`
do
  if [ -d $TARGETPATH/$CURDIR ]; then
    echo "$CURDIR is a directory"
    FILECOUNT=`find $TARGETPATH/$CURDIR -type f | wc -l`
    echo " and there are $FILECOUNT file(s)";
  fi
done
```

Comment: Is that `ls -l` or `ls -1`?  Parsing `ls` output reliably is a dangerous (or, at least, difficult) business, in general; be wary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### before

```
.
├── d1
│   ├── f1
│   ├── f2
│   └── f3
├── d2
│   ├── f4
│   └── f5
└── d3
    ├── d4
    │   └── f9
    ├── f6
    ├── f7
    └── f8
```

#### run the command at top level dir

```
cd /home/pritchea/test

for i in *
do
    [[ -d $i ]] || continue
    n=${i#*-}
    c=$(find "$i" -type f -printf x | wc -c)
    [[ $i == $c-$n ]] && continue
    mv -f "$i" "$c-$n"
done
```

#### after

```
.
├── 2-d2
│   ├── f4
│   └── f5
├── 3-d1
│   ├── f1
│   ├── f2
│   └── f3
└── 4-d3
    ├── d4
    │   └── f9
    ├── f6
    ├── f7
    └── f8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it. I loop over all the directories in `$TARGETPATH`, using `ls -l` to check how many files that are not directories exist in each `$CURDIR`. Note: this might not be the best method (`find -f` might give better results; I haven't checked with symlinks etc).

Because `wc -l` tends to give output that looks similar to `[     1]`, rather than `[1]`, I strip the whitespace using `sed`.

Remove the number from the directory, if one exists, so we can re-run this multiple times and not end up with names that look like this: `2-3-dir`, and also check that the `newdirname` is not the same as `CURDIR`; if it is, there's no point running `mv`.

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGETPATH=.
for CURDIR in `ls -l $TARGETPATH`
do
  if [ -d $TARGETPATH/$CURDIR ]; then
    echo "$CURDIR is a directory"
    #Also strip whitespace from FILECOUNT
    FILECOUNT=$(ls -l $CURDIR | grep ^- | wc -l | sed -e 's/[ \t]*//')
    echo " and there are $FILECOUNT file(s)";

    # We should remove the number from the directory.
    newdirname="$FILECOUNT"-"$(echo "$CURDIR" | sed -e 's/^[0-9]*-//')"
    echo " New directory name: ["$newdirname"]"
    # Now we move the old-dir to the new-dir. 
    if [[ "$CURDIR" != "$newdirname" ]]; then
    mv $TARGETPATH/$CURDIR $TARGETPATH/$newdirname
    fi  
  fi  
done
```